# CheckedListBox ItemCheck event only fires on fast double click?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, checkedlistbox, eventhandler

If you have a CheckedListBox with CheckOnClick = False the ItemCheck event will not fire when the item is checked IF it is first selected...pause...then click again to check the item. But if it is a quick double click with no pause the event will fire.

Is this the correct behavior? The ItemCheck event should fire regardless of the click speed, right?

I believe this is strange behavior that is easy to replicate:

1. Make a new winform
2. add a CheckedListBox and add some items to it. (Leave the default check on click to false)
3. add a label
4. subscribe to ItemCheck event and SelectedIndexChanged make the label's text change when each event fires.

Has anyone else ran into this issue?

**EDIT 5/1/2015**

The problem is that the SelectedIndexChanged event gets fired directly after the ItemCheck event. That means it gets fired before every ItemCheck and then immediately after. The label will not show the change as it happens too fast, but switching to MessageBox.Show() verifies that it is getting fired directly after.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the issue. ItemCheck event gets fired event if the item is selected with one click, and then checked by another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the SelectedIndexChanged event gets fired directly after the ItemCheck event. That means it gets fired before every ItemCheck and then immediately after. The label will not show the change as it happens too fast, but switching to MessageBox.Show() verifies that it is getting fired directly after.

Answer (score 0):

according to MSDN [checkedlistbox.checkonclick](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkonclick.aspx) (**read the remarks section**) check on click property controls whether the list box item is checked on the first click or on the second click. in your case where check on click is flase it requires two clicks to check the item thus **firing the ItemCheck event**.

Comment: I believe you have miss understood the question. It is not about if it checks or not. I am talking about the ItemCheck event and how it does not fire if you use two single clicks compared to a double click which does fire the event.